# How should I get the image path?

Tags: database, magento-1, php-5.4

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

 $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection() 
->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%hp%'))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
//echo $product->getSku();
echo "<ul><li>".$product->getName()."</li>
        <li>".$product->getDescription()."</li> </ul>";
echo '<a href="'.Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_SECURE_URL).'index.php/'.$product->getUrlPath().'"> <img src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product/'.$product->getImage().'"></a>';
    }
?>
```

When I write this code it gives me this output. See the snapshot.. How should I get the image path?

[image]

Comment: Look at what is done in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take it from the helper class

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(100);
```

Comment: lose the resize to get the full size image path, and use `image` instead of `thumbnail` because that's what the OP requested.

Comment: The path of my image is magento/media/catalog/product/then h/2/_/hp.jpg.
how shoul i get this url ?

Answer (score 4):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage());
```

Comment: had a similar need, this worked perfectly for me.